# Empty as a hinge does not work

Tags: physics

I'm following a physifcs course and I added a hinge on a new empty, but it does not behave like I'd expect it to [and what the course shows].
I expected the whole thing to rotate around the hinge, and instead, the whole thing falls down.
Both boxes have active dynamics on it. 
you can see there's a line between empty and objects but it does not work.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, this is exactly the behavior you are specifying: You have two boxes with active dynamics, so both will react to gravity. Joining them with a hinge will only make them fall together.
The hinge must connect to something fixed in the world, if you want it to act the way you want.

Comment: Hmm on the video the guy picks it exactly like that
https://imgur.com/a/nwd1SRT

Comment: Is it possible that the two boxes are supposed to stand on the ground in the tutorial?
In that case, you should check if your ground can collide with your other bodies (eg. set it as a "passive" rigid body)

Comment: Putting them on the ground doesn't change anything unfortunately. Yes, they can collide, it's a passive rigid body.

Comment: Ahhh got it! I didn't see it but he set the left one as a PASSIVE, not both active. and now it rotates around the empty. Thank you for the help, though!

Comment: Glad to hear I could help :-)
Would you mind checking the answer as solved?